# Rotate an object 360° in openGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an object in openGL and I'm able to rotate it using

```
mRenderer.setAngle(mAngle);
```

But this only rotates the shape horizontally. What should be the way so that I can rotate the shape vertically as well?

`mRenderer` is an instance of KubeRenderer

```
class KubeRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public interface AnimationCallback {
        void animate();
    }

    public KubeRenderer(GLWorld world, AnimationCallback callback) {
        mWorld = world;
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.animate();
        }
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -3.0f);
        gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle*0.25f, 1, 0, 0);

        gl.glColor4f(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        mWorld.draw(gl);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float)width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 12);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        mAngle = angle;
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    private GLWorld mWorld;
    private AnimationCallback mCallback;
    private float mAngle;
}
```

Comment: What is the class of `mRenderer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two variables at bottom of class here:
     private float mAngle;

Change these two lines in draw: 
       gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 0, 1, 0);
       gl.glRotatef(mAngle*0.25f, 1, 0, 0);
into lines that rotate on different axis by each variable
(https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml)

and change the setter and getter functions for those three variables however you want ( SetAngle and GetAngle)